# Como actualizar texto mientras se ejecuta función async | Xamarin Forms

Tags: android, visual-studio, xamarin, async-await

Tengo una función que necesito que actualice un span mientras se ejecuta.

```
private async void Button_Clicked_Sincronizar(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            LblBtnSincronizar.Text = "Contador iniciado";

            await Test();

            LblBtnSincronizar.Text = "Fin Contador.";
        }

public async Task Test()
        {
            for (int z = 0; z < 10000; z++)
            {
                SpanInicial.Text = z.ToString();
            }
        }
```

Y solo me muestra el final, no va actualizando el valor mientras se va ejecutando.

Answer (score 0):

Podes agregar de forma rapida `Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread`, pero creo que la mejor opcion seria que trabajaras con `Binding` y evento `OnPropertyChanged`.

```
    private async void Button_Clicked_Sincronizar(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        LblBtnSincronizar.Text = "Contador iniciado";

        await Test();

        LblBtnSincronizar.Text = "Fin Contador.";
    }

    public async Task Test()
    {
        for (int z = 0; z < 10000; z++)
        {
            Device.BeginInvokeOnMainThread(()=>{
                   SpanInicial.Text = z.ToString();
            });
        }
    }
```